# Is there a vectorized approach to conditionally access elements in a Numpy tensor by matrix and row?

Tags: numpy, matrix, vectorization, nested-loops, tensor

Sorry still not very familiar with python so this may be kind of an elementary question. Was wondering if there is a vectorized approach to conditionally access elements in a Numpy tensor by matrix or by row?

Say you have a 3*10*10 Numpy Array X where X=[A,B,C]

```
np.where(X==j)
```

will return something like this:

```
> array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
> 
> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4]),
> 
> array([5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 6, 3, 7, 0, 3, 6]))
```

The row j occupies, along with the integer value of j, constitutes a State. R is a 10*10 matrix of 1's and -1's used to calculate the value of the State. The State value is obtained with the index above. e.g.

> State(0,j) = (R[0][5]+R[0][2]+R[0][3]+R[0][6])/4

```
state0j= np.mean(np.array(R[0][5],R[0][2],R[0][3],R[0][6]))
```

These values would be stored in a 10*10 matrix S such that:

```
 S[0][A[0]==j]= np.mean(np.array(R[0][5],R[0][2],R[0][3],R[0][6]))
 S[2][A[2]==j]= np.mean(np.array(R[2][5],R[2][3],R[2][7])) 
 S[4][A[4]==j]= np.mean(np.array(R[4][5],R[4][0],R[4][3],R[4][6]))
```

Given that S(0,J)!= S(2,J) i.e. the result of j is row dependent, is there a way to figure out S(k,j) for all k and j other than looping through each of the 3 matrices row by row?

Right now I have a very nested loop situation like this:

> **first loop through all the matrices in the tensor**

```
States=[]
for matrix in X:
    S=np.zeros(10*10)
```

> **then loop through all the unique values of each matrix**

```
    for j in np.unique(matrix):  
              place=np.where(matrix==j)
```

> **finally I loop through all the rows the value is found**

```
              for row in np.unique(place[0]):  
                  S[row][A[row]==j]=np.mean(R[row][matrix[row]==j])
    States.append(S)
States=np.stack(States)
StateValue=np.mean(States,axis=0)
```

The last line is indexed to A because that is the original position of j. Is there a faster or more pythonic way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you maybe put this in a mathematical equation?

Comment: Thanks, for pointing that out. I'll make some edits.  I left out a piece of the code I didn't think was relevant but now I see is quite important. S gets appended to a list after iterating through each matrix and then averaged after wards.  A is used to reference the original position of j so it stays fixed throughout the iterations. sum should be j.

Comment: The indenting is a bit strange. Also, the easiest way to show what you want is to show some (short) input and output examples. Otherwise, there's just way too much stream-of-consciousness text for anyone to read.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'll edit the question.